# Programmatic interface to MOUNTVOL.EXE

Tags: windows, usb

Is there any programatic interface for the MOUNTVOL command in Windows? What I am trying to do is get the output from mountvol (even if I have to parse it from the command line), which gives me the list of drives with their GUID-like path (\\?\Volume{...}) and get the device information based on that path (is it a USB drive, VENDOR_ID, etc). Any information on getting that or an alternative method (which works in Win98+) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find the API calls you need in the "Volume Management Functions" portion of the MSDN Library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365730(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can ask on Adv. Win32 api newsgroup (classic question) :
news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
(Mountvol source code, etc)